# Formula in Excel to match a value in two columns with an occurence date of 24 hours difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to match products in two different tables by their product name and date/time. I'm looking to find a match between column A & K if the date in column C occurred 24 hours BEFORE column L.

I have attached a picture of the matches I'm looking for & highlighted the ones that should result in a match.

[image: picture here]

thank you in advance for your help - this is far more advance than my knowledge of excel unfortunately, so I really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: What should the formula return, that that there was a match? You should be able to use `COUNTIFS` for this.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the catch - i mixed up the columns. I'm hoping to return the product name in column A

Comment: So the difference between the dates in columns L and C should be 24 hours or less? Because this is only the case for the first instance of apple. For banana, 7/6/18 10:13... is *more* than 24 hours after 7/5/18 3:07 AM. The second instance of apple is similar...

Comment: in reference to "occurence date of 24 hours difference" .. how does orange match? (in column C it is 10/2 and in column L it is 7/9 .. which is much more than 24 hours...)

Comment: @p._phidot_ sorry about the confusion. I've been looking at this all day i confused myself. I updated the sample data. L & C should be 24 hours or less

Comment: @BigBen should be 24 hours or less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `COUNTIFS`.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($K$2:$K$8,A2,$L$2:$L$8,">="&C2,$L$2:$L$8,"<="&C2+1)>0,A2,"")
```

[image]